# Jquery with & , + and etc signs

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testing() {

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "testing.php",     
           data: "call="+$("#abc").val(),
           success: function(msg){  
            alert( msg );
           }
        });
    }
</script>
<textarea id="abc" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
```

I want to post the data to testing.php but if i got special characters like & sign. it will create the problem. How do i go about it?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testing() {

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "testing.php",     
       data: "call=" + encodeURIComponent($("#abc").val()),
       success: function(msg){  
        alert( msg );
       }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

URL encode those characters.

```
& = &amp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `testing.php` file you can use the function **[addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)** before the data that contains text.